# Library for a Markov Decision Process in C#

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, markov-chains, markov-models

I'm working on a project to create an AI engine, where a robot is exploring a 2D gridded world and has to decide what square to move to next. Are there existing Markov libraries that could be used (ie. I would just change the parameters), or samples that exist?

Answer (score 3):

[Accord.Net](http://code.google.com/p/accord/) might help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can tweak this: [Hidden Markov Models in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69647/Hidden-Markov-Models-in-C)